# Understanding this context in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, this

normally i would use this to load dependency

```
main: function() {
   require(['views/home'], function(HomeView) {
       _pageView.render(HomeView);
   });
}
```

but now am looking of simplifying it by doing this

```
main: function() {
        require(['views/home'], this.homeView);
},

homeView: function(HomeView) {
   this.page = _pageView.render(HomeView);
}
```

but the keyword `this` is unrecognizable. How to make it recognizable.

Comment: What do `main` and `homeView` belong to? And what do you mean by "`this` is unrecognizable"?

Comment: actually this is part of backbone.view code. The this keyword is undefined that make the render process is imposible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `require` like this:

```
require(['views/home'], this.homeView.bind(this));
```

should prevent `this` from getting set to a different value when RequireJS calls the callback.